# How to repeat action for all the files in a folder?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, batch, processing, watermark

I've created an action in photoshop to create watermark for my images and its working fine but i want to repeat it for all the images from a specific folder.

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like what you're looking for [Watermarking Photos (Batch)](http://photoshop911.typepad.com/help/2004/04/watermarking_ph.html).

Comment: @Vijay: No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can further automate this process using a Photoshop droplet. Droplets let you drag a folder onto a droplet icon. Then Photoshop performs a specified action on all items in the directory.

Here's a video of me demonstrating how to create and use a droplet using a Save as JPG action, but you can apply the same principle to your own actions: http://vimeo.com/11366445